# Droidcam not connecting to opencv

Tags: opencv, android-camera

I am trying to connect the feed from droidcam from my phone to opencv for face detection. But i am not able to connect the camera to opencv

I am using this code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.131.140:4747/mjpegfeed')
```

when i use 0 instead of URL, it works fine with the default webcam.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with (windows 10, intellij Idea, droicam)

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(1); // 0 : is for the default Camera and 1 : for your smartphone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look that's because you must grab the image path not only the ip direction.
Ex.
http://192.168.131.140:4747/mjpegfeed?640x480

This way works for me.
Let me know if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Droid_Cam_Client and connected it through WIFI to my mobile camera.

```py
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(2) #if you open Skype for example you can find the right source name for Droid_Cam at camera settings.
```

I tried face_recognition using the above way with my mobile camera and it works fine. :)

It didn't work for me either using IP